# Tex Studio is not working all of a sudden. Saying *sty files not found

Tags: packages, texstudio

I have been using TexStudio this week. Just yesterday, I decided to shutdown my computer. Today I restarted it and opened TexStudio. But, all of a sudden it is not compiling anymore. It comes with error saying that some *sty file is not found. For example setspace.sty not found as given in the[image]. I then remove it, but it then says titling.sty not found. However, the document seems to compile well with Texworks. So I am really confused what the problem is?

Can someone help?

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: if texowrks can find your tex then it must still be installed so it must just be your settings in texstudio specifying the wrong paths to tex.

Comment: @Bernard MikTex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is working fine now. I will close the question. You were right - there was some issue with the MiKTex path.

Comment: unrelated but it's best not to use utf8x option to inputenc, use utf8 (or don't use the package at all as utf8 is the default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay go t it. Do you know how can I close the question?

Comment: as author you should have a delete button under the question I believe? Or we could vote to close but that takes 5 people.